# python mysql connection.cursor().execute fails on the second query

Tags: python, mysql

I am using `mysql.connector` in Python 3.

This works the first time it is called, but not the second.

```
def execute (self, query, *args):
     c = self.connection.cursor (prepared = True)
     return c.execute (query, args)
```

I was expecting it to create a new cursor for each query, but I am getting surprising errors.

```
print (dbobject.execute ("CALL MyProc(%s);", 1))
print (dbobject.execute ("CALL MyProc(%s);", 1))
```

The output is

```
MySQLCursorPrepared: CALL MyProc(%s);
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py/DB.py", line 348, in <module>
    print (db.execute ("CALL MyPro (%s);", 1))
  File "py/DB.py", line 156, in execute
    c = self.connection.cursor (prepared = True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 810, in cursor
    self.handle_unread_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 1063, in handle_unread_result
    raise errors.InternalError("Unread result found")
```

If instead I

```
print (list (dbobject.execute ("CALL MyProc(%s);", 1)))
print (list (dbobject.execute ("CALL MyProc(%s);", 1)))
```

then the first one prints a list of results, the second one throws

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1210: Incorrect number of arguments executing prepared statement
```

Assuming a single thread owns the database object, I would like to have one compiled prepared statement object (*is that what MySQLCursor represents?*) for each of the fixed set of predefined queries, and generate a new prepared statement for each dynamically-build query on demand. I expected `dbobject.connection.cursor()` to return a new object each time it is called, but the above errors hint that state is being shared in some way and the subsequent `execute` calls are not being handled independently.

How should I use prepared statement objects/cursors in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass an integer instead of an argument array.

Instead of

```
dbobject.execute("CALL MyProc(%s);", 1)
```

Use

```
dbobject.execute("CALL MyProc(%s);", (1,))
```

It should work.

Comment: I am passing a tuple: `*args` is a variadic argument list, `args` is the tuple in `def execute (self, query, *args): ... return c.execute (query, args)`